# Can a Hyperledger fabric peer be scaled horizontally?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger

As transactions keep coming in, disk space on each peer is bound to get filled up, because each peer needs to have a complete copy of the blockchain. Is there a way to horizontally scale each peer for disk space ? rather than vertically scaling it (getting a larger disk) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you mean is tasking a number of "local" peers to act together as one single "logical peer" and distribute the storage and management of the "logical peer" Ledger state among themselves (e.g. via some partitioning strategy on the stored state; for the Blockchain maybe based on chaincode-separation?).

To my knowledge this does not exist and most probably is not even planned at this stage. Two things are to note, however.

1.) The size of the blockchain is determined by a number of factors - it does not have to be Bitcoin-sized! (Incidentally, even that isn't unmanageably large; https://blockchain.info/charts/blocks-size) There is even thinking about using Blockchain in IoT settings (see K. Christidis and M. Devetsikiotis, “Blockchains and Smart Contracts for the Internet of Things,” IEEE Access, vol. PP, no. 99, pp. 1–1, 2016.).

2.) In many Blockchain use cases, not all nodes "need" to store every block since the first (genesis) one. I think "pruning" is even discussed in the original Satoshi paper. My knowledge is very limited on this (I think this is only being discussed for Bitcoin and not implemented yet); that being said, I think it is reasonable to assume that Hyperledger can be modified to support various pruning strategies. To the best of my knowledge, however, it does not do this as of now.

Comment: One more thing: technically, you _may_ be able to swap out the underlying RocksDB of the Hyperledger peer to $DISTRIBUTED_KV_STORAGE_OF_YOUR_CHOICE, but based on my limited knowledge of the source code this is nontrivial and may open up a whole new range of exciting problems.

Comment: correct, in the next iteration (summer 2016), we will be exploring "pruning" or archiving older blocks of a blockchain.